# Integrating wordpress with website written in JSP

Tags: wordpress, apache, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have my website which is developed using Spring MVC using JSP. I wanted to integrate the wordpress blog to the website. I.e Install wordpress on the webserver and have it linked to the site menu.

The site is hosted on AWS with apache tomcat and database used is RDS.

I have read some pointers on integrating but most of them suggest using iframes. Is that the only solution? Can someone share some thoughts?

Appreciate your help

Best, 
Donald

Comment: Depending on your hosting you can put your Apache Tomcat behind Apache HTTPd with mod_jk and redirect requests to Tomcat depending on URL...

Answer (score 1):

@see: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API

Wordpress has a XML RMI api. You can use it to obtain content and for submitting new blog items.